# $_FILES returns empty using DropzoneJS and Symfony 1.4

Tags: javascript, php, upload, symfony-1.4, dropzone.js

I've scoured through several SO and blog posts online but can't find something that works.

I'm trying to set up a simple HTML drag and drop form where users can upload several files at once via DropzoneJS.

### HTML:

```
<form action='<?php echo url_for("@menu_basic_menu"); ?>' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="basic_menu_dropzone"></form>

<button id="file_submit_btn" type="submit" form='basic_menu_dropzone' value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

### Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var dropzone = new Dropzone('#basic_menu_dropzone', {
        paramName: 'files',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
    });

    $('#file_submit_btn').click(function() {
        dropzone.processQueue();
    });
});
```

Here you'll notice that I also set up a submit button such that we only start the upload process of the files on submit

### PHP (snippet of actions.class.php):

```
public function executeBasicMenu(sfWebRequest $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        print_r_tree($_FILES);
    }
  }
```

I have everything setup so that executeBasicMenu is properly fired on submit, but $_FILES always returns an empty array.

### Notes:

- If I replace the dropzone form with a regular input type='file' tag then everything works, so my gut feeling is telling me my configuration with dropzone is wrong somewhere.
- I've stepped through the dropzone.js source code and it looks like right when it's about to send the data on line 1386: xhr.send(formData),
  formData is empty.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Q: does `echo url_for("@menu_basic_menu");` give you the correct URL?  Something like `"/file-upload"`?

Comment: Yup. I've also confirmed this because the resulting action gets fired. Also, like I mentioned in my question, switching out the dropzone form for a normal <input type='file'> tag works properly (i.e. the action gets fired, and $_FILE returns a propery array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my mistakes!

In my code, I was submitting the form on the button click:

```
<button id="file_submit_btn" type="submit" form='basic_menu_dropzone' value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

But I was also trying to call processQueue() on the same button click.
However, the form would be submitted before the files would get sent so no files would be received on the PHP side.

I also incorrectly instantiated my dropzone instance - I should have included a parallelUploads field so that I could upload multiple files at once.

So with my new updated code, everything works as expected and I can get a handle on my files on the PHP side!

## Solution

#### Html

```
<form action='<?php echo url_for("@menu_basic_menu"); ?>'method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="basic_menu_dropzone"></form>
<button id="file_submit_btn" type="button" form='basic_menu_dropzone' value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

#### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var dropzone = new Dropzone('#basic_menu_dropzone', {
        paramName: 'files',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 10
    });

    $('#file_submit_btn').click(function() {
        dropzone.processQueue();
    });
});
```

#### PHP

```
public function executeBasicMenu(sfWebRequest $request) {
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
      error_log($tmpName);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others too!